# Update On Millions of Records or Join While Loading in CSV

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm working on importing a CSV into a Mysql table that has roughly 11.8 million rows. As it stands right now I'm using the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` method of mysql to load the data. This part is fine takes roughly 10 minutesish to load all 11.8 mil.

The problem comes afterwards whenever I need to update all of the records with data from another table. I have a working (and currently running but nearing the 24 hour mark) process that runs an update all on the table. I'm starting to question if there isn't a faster way of doing this.

One idea I had was during the process I'm splitting the CSV into 100k line files and processing those. I could do an update as the 100k lines get added by only updating where the fields that are being populated by the join are null. Another idea is to try to run some preprocessing on the CSV to add the data to it and then upload it using the quick method.

Overall just contemplating what the best method of doing the update is while the one I wrote is running. Any help / ideas would be awesome!

Sidenote: This process is only run yearly so it doesn't have to be amazingly optimized, but I'd like to have some glimmer of hope that once the data is in staging it won't take an extremely long time to move it to production

Comment: Preprocessing the CSV may result in the fastest total upload action, assuming the modifications you need are straightforward. But 24 hours may be excessive for an 11M join. Do you have indexes defined between them, and have you run an `EXPLAIN` on the `UPDATE` query to determine if it is able to use the indexes? Unless running on an underpowered server, I might expect an hour or two, but not 24+.

Comment: It's running on an AWS EC2 / RDS setup at the moment. I have not run an explain. I'll have to try that, the problem is the update actually starts through a rake task because the joins + `update_all` happen through some ruby code. That may be some of the slow down as well.

Comment: You should include the rake task in your question.

Comment: I will momentarily but the rake task is just wrapping an Active Record connection that calls a class method with all the join / update all logic

Comment: task import: :environment do
    year = ENV['YEAR'].to_i
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      PublicHMDA.update_with_census_data(year)
    end

    p "Updated all the records"
  end

Comment: Can you paste the update SQL?